# How to use AWS S3 Route 53 with Gmail business domain?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, amazon-aws, amazon-s3, route53

I have a business domain hosted in google Daniels@mycompany.com and now I want to make my website hosted in AWS S3 hosting. Problem is that Route 53 in AWS console is asking to add 4 NS records, but I already have 5 MX records for Google email service. Domain service shows this error when I try to add NS record with MX records already there.

> NS and DS records are not allowed with other records

When I contacted my domain company they told I should ask AWS solve it, but they don't have phone support for my plan.

Here is a screenshot from current records:

[image]

How can I solve it manually, so that I can have my Gmail business mail and AWS S3 hosting with same domain?

Comment: Your NS records need to be set at your domain registrar.   They control which DNS servers your domain uses.   Route 53 is asking you to change this because it wants to be your DNS host.   If you do so, none of the records at your current DNS host will be used any more.  You can switch DNS hosts, but make sure you have copied all your records over.   Make sure that route53 has all your MX, CNAME, and TXT records set up properly before making the switch.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ohhhh I deleted TXT, CNAME but transfered only MX records. Do you know how can I find them now in google console?

Comment: *"When I contacted my domain company they told I should ask AWS solve it."*  Classic.  Who's your domain company (registrar)?  Because *that* is where the change needs to be made.  You are not trying to add NS records.  You are trying to change your authoritative nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

In the AWS Route 53 console, get the name of the four name servers they provide, you will need these for step two.

**Step 2:**

Log in to the website of the Registrar from whom you bought your domain name. Input those four name servers provided my Route 53 into the Registrar's management console. You do not need any other record of any type whatsoever at the Registrar, so you can remove everything else or leave it, makes no difference.

**Step 3:**

Return to the AWS Route 53 console and add your MX records for Google, [described here on Google's help page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6149697?hl=en).

**Step 4:**

Continuing to work in the AWS Route 53 console, add any other settings you need such as A and CNAME records. Describing these is beyond the scope of your question but you can find this information online easily.

**Step 5:**

Wait at least an hour for your settings to 'propagate', which is just a fancy way of saying it takes a while for everyone else's computers to notice your settings have changed. Test here if you want something to do while you wait: https://www.whatsmydns.net/

That's all, you are done. If you made errors in your DNS settings on Route 53 you have to look at the documentation from your email and/or web hosting providers and make sure you followed these precisely.